# Declare object of derived class without specifying it

Tags: c++, inheritance, types, declare

There is a base-class Base and two possible derived classes DerivedA and DerivedB. How can I declare a variable without specifying (at the point of declaration) which of the two derived classes will be in use?

I have tried the following example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;
#include <stdlib.h>


struct Base
{
    int base = 0;
};

struct DerivedA : Base
{
    int x = 1;
};

struct DerivedB : Base
{
    int y = 1;
};


class Test
{
public:
    Test(int a)
    {
    Base TestObj;
    if (a==0)
    {
        DerivedA TestObj; // intention: change type of TestObj to DerivedA
    }
    else
    {
        DerivedB TestObj; // intention: change type of TestObj to DerivedB
    }

    TestObj.base = 7;

    if (a==0)
    {
        TestObj.x = 2;
    }
    else
    {
        TestObj.y = 4;
    }

    myObjs.push_back(make_shared<Base>(TestObj));
    }
private:
    vector<shared_ptr<Base>> myObjs;

};
```

The compiler will throw an error saying "error: ‘struct Base’ has no member named ‘x’ " (or 'y' respectively).

A trivial solution would be to include everything in the first if (a==0) / else statements using a separate myObjs.push_back call for the two cases. However, I am interested in a solution where I can stay more flexible, ideally by e.g. only changing the line 'Base TestObj;' to something more general. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't change the types of objects at run-time.

Comment: C++ is a *statically* typed language. Not a dynamically typed one.

Comment: @NeilButterworth: You're nitpicking... you can reinterpret at run time; and then there are variants and any's, whose type you can sort-of change. See my answer below.

Comment: @einpoklum To quote from your very own answer - "you just can't have that."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to keep the flow the same, then you just need to make `TestObj` a `std::shared_ptr<Base>` to begin with.  That would make the code

```
Test(int a)
{
    std::shared_ptr<Base> TestObj;
    if (a==0)
    {
        TestObj = std::make_shared<DerivedA>();
    }
    else
    {
        TestObj = std::make_shared<DerivedB>(); 
    }

    TestObj->base = 7;

    if (a==0)
    {
        static_cast<DerivedA&>(*TestObj).x = 2; // need the cast so you can set the member
    }
    else
    {
        static_cast<DerivedB&>(*TestObj).y = 4; // need the cast so you can set the member
    }

    myObjs.push_back(TestObj);
}
```

Comment: Nice answer! I was typing mine up around the same time, and made it a bit smoother (maybe).

Answer (score 2):

"How can I declare a variable without specifying (at the point of declaration) which of the two derived classes will be in use?" - You cannot.

In C++ every variable has to have a *single* type at the point of declaration. No way around that.

You *can*, however, use a pointer to the base class. That will accept being assigned any derived type and can be used to call functions in derived types through virtual/dynamic dispatch.

Comment: Jesper: It's possible to specify indirectly using typedefs, TMP, etc.

Comment: @einpoklum any variable will still end up with a single static type.

Comment: Yes, it would, but it still meets OPs request on the rhetorical level.

Comment: Thanks everyone. Using std::shared_ptr<Base> TestObj; I can now also assign the derived types. When accessing TestObj (after instantiation of class Test) later on, I still have to use the static_cast<DerivedA/B> trick when trying to access members of the derived class?? Or is there any way around/ better way?

Answer (score 2):

I guess you need something like this:

```
std::shared_ptr<Base> TestObj;
if (a==0)
{
    TestObj = std::make_shared<DerivedA>();
}
else
{
    TestObj = std::make_shared<DerivedB>();
}

TestObj->base = 7;

if (a==0)
{
    static_cast<DerivedA*>(TestObj.get())->x = 2;
}
else
{
    static_cast<DerivedB*>(TestObj.get())->y = 4;
}

myObjs.push_back(std::move(TestObj));
```

Comment: This is a good answer! In general, though, I'd recommend `std::unique_ptr` unless there's a specific reason onwership needs to be shared

Answer (score 2):

If you are willing to make `Test` a class template, you have the ability to choose the object type based on the value of `a`.

```
template <int a>
class Test
{
   TypeSelector<a> TestObj;
   ...
};
```

where

```
template <int a> class TypeSelectorHelper;

template <> class TypeSelectorHelper<0>
{
   using type = DerivedA;
}

template <> class TypeSelectorHelper<1>
{
   using type = DerivedB;
}

template <int a> 
using TypeSelector = typename TypeSelectorHelper<a>::type;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make your code a wee bit more succinct:

```
class Test
{
  public:
    Test(int a) {
        std::shared_ptr<Base> TestObj;
        if (a == 0) {
            std::shared_ptr<DerivedA> TestA  = std::make_shared<DerivedA>();
            TestA->x = 2;
            TestObj = TestA;
        }
        else {
            std::shared_ptr<DerivedB> TestB = std::make_shared<DerivedB>();
            TestB->y = 4;
            TestObj = TestB;
        }
        TestObj->base = 7;
        myObjs.push_back(TestObj);
    }
  private:
    vector<shared_ptr<Base>> myObjs;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do *exactly* what you want: Declaring a variable means specifying its type; and if you want the variable to have the type DerivedA or the type DerivedB, with a decision at run-time - you just can't have that.

But all is not lost!

### If you can determine the type at compile-time

You can define the type based on a meta-computation, within the compiler, which produces the type. This is [@RSahu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57632212/1593077):

```
constexpr bool determine_if_we_need_derived_a() { /* ... compile-time computation ... */ }
using type_i_need = typename type_selector<determine_if_we_need_derived_a()>::type;
```

### If you can't determine the type at compile-time...

#### ... but you know it's either `DerivedA` or `DerivedB` only

You can use an [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant): A fancier, safer, nicer version of a C-style union:

```
std::variant<DerivedA, DerivedB> get_derived(/*params here*/)
{
    // etc.
    if (condition) { return DerivedA( /* ... */); }
    else           { return DerivedB( /* ... */); }
}

// ...

auto derived_object = get_derived(arg1, arg2, /* etc. */);
```

but of course you'll need to use [visitation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit) afterwards, so as to apply the appropriate action depending on the actual type that's in your `derived_object`.

#### ... but you don't know much of anything

You probably don't have much choice other than to use a pointer, like @NathanOliver and others suggest:

```
std::unique_ptr<Base> get_derived(/*params here*/)
{
    // etc.
    if (condition) { return std::make_unique<DerivedA>(/* ... */); }
    else           { return std::make_unique<DerivedB>(/* ... */); }
}

// ...

myObjs.emplace_back(std::move(get_derived(arg1, arg2, /* etc. */)));
```

#### ... and you're feeling frisky

You can try [`std::any`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any). You can put *anything*, of *any type* in it! Now, it's *not* the right abstraction for the job, but it's fun to learn about. The catch is, that you'll essentially need to know what type an `std::any` holds before you can retrieve the value and use it.

Another idea is, instead of storing pointers to values, to store an opaque lambda object (no pointer or anything) in your `myObjs` (which would become `myObjActions` or something), then invoke those lambdas when necessary. All of these lambdas will need to have the same type though! ... so in a sense you would only be relegating the problem to what happens within the lambda.

Comment: @NeilButterworth: So, did you upvote, or downvote? If it's the latter - care to comment?